# getting file path through browse button

Tags: html

i have put a browse button in my html form. with the help of it i just want to get only the file path not the file itself. for ex: if i browse to "D:\Raghu\hgg" all i want is the path itself, not the "hgg" folder. is it possible? any hint is very much appreciated.

Comment: sorry i dont know, but whats HTA

Answer (score 3):

All modern browsers will only give you the filename; this is due to some sort of security issue. All versions of IE will give you the complete path though (you have to change a security setting to get the complete path in IE8).

In short, I don't think you can't get the full path these days.

Answer (score -1):

If `hgg` is filename then it should be possible. Just attach `change` event to the input, and read `input.value` to get real filename (without path):

```
<input type="file" id="t" />
<script>
    document.getElementById("t").addEventListener("change", function() {
        alert(this.value);
    }, false);
</script>
```

Comment: `input[type=file]` doesn't allow to select a folder - you have to choose a file.